# PHP Checkbox checked is not working correctly when comparing 2 Arrays

Tags: php

I trying to compare 2 Arrays and then let the Checkbox to be checked if there are common values between them.

**coding**

```
$array_1[]="value1";
$array_1[]="value2";
$array_1[]="value3";
$array_1[]="value4";
$array_1[]="value5";
$array_1[]="value6";
$array_1[]="value7";
$array_1[]="value8";

$array_2[]="value1";
$array_2[]="value3";
$array_2[]="value4";


for($i=0;$i<count($array_1);$i++){
    $checked = isset($array_2[$i])? 'checked' : '';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" ' . $checked .' name="zzz[] "value="'.$array_1[$i].'"> '.$array_1[$i].'<br>';
}
```

[image]

**as you can see from the screenshot, the correct result should be right side with value1, value3 and value4. However, my php output is leftside of the screenshot**

Anyone knows what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working on values, and not on keys, you should use `in_array` check

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array_1);$i++){
    $checked = in_array($array_1[$i], $array_2) ? 'checked' : '';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" ' . $checked .' name="zzz[] "value="'.$array_1[$i].'"> '.$array_1[$i].'<br>';
}
```

Alternatively, you can set the keys to be the same, as Nadir Latif suggests

Answer (score 1):

The value2 array initialization is wrong. It should be:

```
$array_2[1]="value1";
$array_2[3]="value3";
$array_2[4]="value4";
```